# Glossary in Latex

Tags: glossaries, appendices

using the following code I am not able to get a glossary printed out in the appendix:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,  11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[section,numberedsection, acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
It follows that the European Economic Integration denotes the  elimination of economic frontiers in Europe, referring to the integration process following the second world war, concerning mainly  the \acrfull{eu}.
\begin{appendices}
\chead{{\footnotesize Appendix A}}
\fancypagestyle{FooBar}
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
\section{} \label{Appendix1}
\printglossary[title={Custom Title}]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The acronym works in the main body of the document, but does not prin in the appendix.
What is wrong?

**EDIT**

after googling and reading through the glossaries documentation, it is probable that to print glossaries I need to use windows prompt and type the makeindex  command . command. however, i am first-time user of windows prompt so does someone have a "for dummies" explanation what exactly to type there and how to link the folder containing my thesis there?

Comment: Your example misses `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

Comment: sorry, corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

Either try to use `\printacronyms` instead of `\printglossary` or `\printglossary[type=acronym]` (+ some additional options)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,  11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[section,numberedsection, acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\newacronym{eu}{EU}{European Union}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
It follows that the European Economic Integration denotes the  elimination of economic frontiers in Europe, referring to the integration process following the second world war, concerning mainly  the \acrfull{eu}.
\begin{appendices}
\chead{{\footnotesize Appendix A}}
\fancypagestyle{FooBar}
\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}
\section{} \label{Appendix1}
% \printglossary[title={Custom Title}]

\printacronyms[title={Custom Title}]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, but unfortunately it did not help :/
might be because of a conflict with another package?

Comment: @MartinHulényi: Well, I used the packages from your example, so what should I say about any other package you use in addition. Perhaps you should update your TeX distribution as well

Comment: I think that I need to use prompt with the command makindex (See edit above)

Comment: That's well documented in the manual